# Realism as necessary for impredicative mathematics to avoid viscous circle, but not really?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, philosophy-of-language, goedel, foundations-of-mathematics

Here is an quote from Godel from Shapiro’s *Thinking About Mathematics*:

“…the vicious circle…applies only if the entities are constructed by ourselves. In this case, there must clearly exist a definition… which does not refer to a totality to which the object defined belongs, because the construction of a thing can certainly not be based on a totality of things to watch the thing to be constructed belongs. If,  however, it is a question of objects that exist independently of our constructions, there is nothing in the least absurd in the existence of totalities containing members, which can be described (i.e. uniquely characterized) only by reference to this totality… it seems to me that the assumption of such objects is quite as legitimate as the assumption of physical bodies and there is quite as much reason to believe in their existence.”

So without impredicativeness, “the least upper bound” is viciously circular. But with it is no more problematic than “the town drunk” (semi paraphrased from Shapiro).

So *if* objects exist platonically (separately), there is nothing absurd about “totalities containing members”.

What if you take the staunchest anti-platonist (Hartry Field?) who rejects platonic objects exist and ask them if they understand Godel’s definition of the least upper bound? I’m sure he will have no problems, and be able to apply it just as the platonist would.

So now isn’t Godel’s quote more appropriately something like, “If a definition makes sense in language (has meaning) it is unproblematic”?

For someone may doubt platonism as much as their strongest convictions, yet they understand Godel’s impredicative math.

Famously this is a major reason Godel was a realist. I’m asking, isn’t this (Field understanding) more and firstly evidence realism is not required at all? The above makes me highly suspicious of realism and realism’s necessity for impredicativeness, ergo fictionalism. But Godel was convinced, so what am I missing here?

It almost feels like Godel is holding mathematics hostage. *There must be this accompanying ontological belief*. Well Hartry doesn’t have it yet presumably does higher set theory.

Comment: I haven't read the source, by my impression of the quote is that Godel is not talking about our ability to do math, but about our confidence that it is consistent. If you just construct a structure out of your imagination and invent a theory around it, how can you be confident that the theory is consistent (assuming that you can't prove the consistency).

Comment: @DavidGudeman Consistency isn’t the only desideratum and talented mathematicians rise to top doubting PA consistency (Ed Nelson). Yet Nelson would say PA and math are useful even if they aren’t consistent or may not be consistent. And what would Priest say about this? This seems absolutely fatal to any realism which says there must be realism for math to “work”.

Comment: Note that according to [this section](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/platonism-mathematics/#TruValRea) of the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy article on mathematical platonism, "realism" in the philosophy of mathematics can have different definitions--there are some who are truth-value realists in the sense that they think that every member of some class of propositions (say, all propositions in first-order arithmetic) has a definite truth-value regardless of whether people ever discover it, but they do not think that this requires an ontology where numbers exist as abstract objects.

Comment: "Consistency isn’t the only desideratum and talented mathematicians rise to top doubting PA consistency (Ed Nelson)" Nelson has apparently withdrawn his claim about his specific argument that PA is inconsistent, see his comment [here](https://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2011-October/015832.html) (linked from [this discussion](https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/gsvQSpeDHKXxjXwuM/edward-nelson-claims-proof-of-inconsistency-in-peano)), but it may still be fair to say that he has little confidence in PA's consistency.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Thanks for the link of true-value realism. That seems to allow for Field to understand impredicativeness without a platonic ontology. Did Godel for some reason disbelieve in such metaphysics? Yes Nelson retracted but he clearly did not need to hold a realist ontology to practice math, the same math (axiomatic set theory) which forced Godel into platonism(?!)

Comment: The argument (if that is his argument) relies on the confidence mathematicians have that arithmetic is consistent and appeals to the justification for that confidence. Yes, this means that Nelson and a few other mathematicians may not find the argument persuasive on that basis, but the vast majority of mathematicians do believe PA is consistent. And even if the argument doesn't go through, that wouldn't be fatal for realism because there are other arguments for realism.

Comment: @DavidGudeman I’m definitely not certain that’s Godel’s argument, but from the quote and my first pass through Shapiro it seemed something like it is being said. That this turned him ontologically Platonist. It seems like he concedes it is *absurd* for math to study such objects unless they are platonic. It seems like he skips over the possibility of truth value realism Hypnosifl linked, where math can study them even if they aren’t platonic. Is consistency really central to this point? Maybe I’m grossly mistaking Godel’s beliefs and arguments.